# /dev/nvme1n1p1 requires a manual fsck

Tags: boot, system

today when I booted Linux it gave me this error:
[image]

What can I do? I'm Linux noob, so can u help me step by step? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try `sudo fsck /dev/nvme1n1p1`, enter your password, let it do its thing, say 'yes' to everything, and then reboot the system.

Comment: I've tried, and it tells me: "sh: sudo not found".

Comment: It has been a while since I've seen that screen. Does it ask you to login? Worst-case scenario, you can use a Live USB (or DVD) instance, boot to it, make sure the drive isn't mounted, and run fsck from there. If it asks you to login, be sure to login first and then sudo *should* work? You can also try it without sudo, but memory tells me that sudo is required. I haven't seen that screen in ages and I'm not sure how I can force my eOS install to show that screen.

Comment: Let me explain the scenario, I currently have Elementary and Windows installed in dual boot, Windows on the main ssd of the laptop, while linux on another nvme ssd apart. When I turn on it asks me which of the two os start, however Elementary does not ask me the login, starts immediately with the errors that I showed you.

Comment: Yes, I gathered that. Follow the previous directions and you should get it sorted. Worst case scenario, just use a Live USB and boot from that. It doesn't even matter which distro you use for the Live USB. Just make sure that the drive is unmounted and run fsck.